# В цикле "съедается" часть элемента массива

Tags: php, циклы

Здравствуйте.
Пишу модуль под DLE и столкнулся с проблемой, что при переборке массива, отданного API DLE съедается значение элемента массива, остается только первый символ.

Вот, собственно, сам цикл

```
   foreach($usonline as $usr){
            $lusers = $lusers.'<a href = "/user/'.$usr['name'].'/">'.$usr['name'].'</a> ';
          }
```

Пробовал еще так

```
while($usr = current($usonline)){
  $lusers = $lusers.'<a href = "/user/'.$usr['name'].'/">'.$usr['name'].'</a> '; 
  next($usonline);
}
```

Эффект везде один. После цикла var_dump() отдает:

```
string(27) "<a href = "/user/A/">A</a> "
```

Хотя на месте этой А должно быть Admin.

От базы приходят полные данные.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: покажите `var_dump()` переменной `$usonline`. Тут кажется проблема String и Char

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev вот `array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Admin"
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если структура массива `array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Admin" }`  тогда ваш код не будет работать. Придется сделать так

```
$usonline = array("name"=>"Admin");
$lusers ='';

foreach($usonline as $usr){
    $lusers = $lusers.'<a href = "/user/'.$usr.'/">'.$usr.'</a> ';
}
echo $lusers;
```

А в Вашем случае, что бы показались все пользователи (с вашим кодом), структура массива должна быть так

```
 array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Admin" } }
```

или в `php`

```
$usonline = array();
$usonline[0] = array ("name" => "Admin");

var_dump($usonline);

 foreach($usonline as $usr){
          $lusers = $lusers.'<a href = "/user/'.$usr['name'].'/">'.$usr['name'].'</a> ';
 }

echo $lusers;
```

Comment: Т.е. средствами DLE API этого не добиться, я так понимаю?

Comment: почему можете проверить из чего состоит переменная, массив или нет и будете использовать нужный код. Вы можете показать переменную с 2я пользователями. не только админ.